# Dynamically change parent according to its most prior child jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Working on task module and there are different task colors according to its due date and tasks will be under diffrent categories (accordion).

We want to set the color of  categories (accordion) according to its most prior task e.g. where task class "task-overdue-hard" is high priority over  "task-overdue".

> Priority:
>   task-overdue-hard,task-overdue,task-due,task-default,task-completed

```js
    $('#sub_created_accordion .panel').each(function () {
        var classes = "";
        $(this).find('.task').each(function () {
            classes += $(this).attr('class') + " ";
        });
        classes = classes.replace(/task /g,"");
        $(this).find('.panel-heading').addClass(classes)
    });
```

```css
/* Common styles for all types */
.task {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-left-width: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.task h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.task p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.task code {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/* Tighten up space between multiple callouts */
.task + .task {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
/* Variations */
.task-completed {
  border-left-color: #a5a5a5;
  color: #a5a5a5;
}
.task-default {
  border-left-color: #5bc0de;
}
.task-due {
  border-left-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.task-overdue {
  border-left-color: #d9534f;
}
.task-overdue-hard {
  border-left-color: #d9534f;
  color: #d9534f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="sub_created_accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading task-head-completed task-head-overdue task-head-overdue-hard task-head-due" role="tab" id="heading_created_3">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub_accordion" href="#collapse_created_3" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_created_3">
                                    First Category <i class="fa pull-right fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>
                                </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse_created_3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="task task-completed">
          <h4>Title 3</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="task task-overdue">
          <h4>Title 2</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="task task-overdue-hard">
          <h4>Title 4</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="task task-due">
          <h4>Title 1</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading task-head-due" role="tab" id="heading_created_2">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub_accordion" href="#collapse_created_2" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_created_2">
                                    Second Category <i class="fa pull-right fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i>
                                </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse_created_2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="task task-due">
          <h4>Task 2 Wishlist </h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: __Client requirement :__, Then solve it yourself others are not getting paid

Comment: Right now you just take all the classes and don't care what's the priority. What's the problem storing the classes in different vars and the append them?

Comment: Can please explain how it will be work?

Comment: Right now you're searching on .find(".task") and store everything inside one var without prio order whatsoever. Instead of doing this search for the .task overdu and store in a var overdu, overdu hard in a var overdu hard. concact everything in order use your replace then append to parent the whole string.

Comment: OK but this is looking more time consuming process because then we need to do this for all classes e.g task-overdue-hard,task-overdue,task-due,task-default,task-completed

Comment: there's no difference between accessing $(".task") $(this) or (".task-overdue"). Each time it will query the dom to get that element. Anyway i don't see why you append all the class to the parent. And use @ to notify an user.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#sub_created_accordion .panel').each(function () {
  if($(this).find(".task-overdue-hard").length>0){
  class1="task-overdue-hard";
  }
  else if($(this).find(".task-overdue").length>0){
   class1="task-overdue";
  }
  else if($(this).find(".task-due").length>0){
   class1="task-due";
  }
  else if($(this).find(".task-default").length>0){
   class1="task-default";
   }
  else if($(this).find(".task-completed").length>0){
   class1="task-completed";
   }
   $(this).addClass(class1+"parent");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/anubala/aL4kfw98/1/